# GetX - How to return a value from Get.Dialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

How can I get a return value from a Get.Dialog that opens a Dialog Widget / AlertDialog?

Answer (score 17):

#### 1. GetMaterialApp

In your main.dart, ensure `MyApp` is returning a `GetMaterialApp` instead of `MaterialApp`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp( // <-- Use GetMaterialApp
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Examples'),
    );
  }
}
```

This allows Get to handle navigation / routing, making Navigation methods available such as: `Get.to()`, `Get.dialog()`, `Get.back()`, etc.  Without `GetMaterialApp` as the root of your app you'll see a (confusing) error when calling any of the navigation methods:

```
E/flutter (11139): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: 
'package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart': Failed assertion: 
line 453 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.
```

#### 2. Get.dialog + Get.back(result: X)

Have your call to `Get.dialog` expect an async return value ...

```
onPressed: () async {
  // assign return value to an observable
  return lx.result.value = await Get.dialog(
```

... which gets returned when the dialog is closed using `Get.back(result: X)` where `X` is a dynamic value returned via `Get.dialog`:

```
onPressed: () => Get.back(result: true),
```

#### Complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class LoginX extends GetxController {
  RxBool result = false.obs;
}

class GetDialogReturnPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final LoginX lx = Get.put(LoginX());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GetDialog Return Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Obx(() => Text('Value shows here: ${lx.result.value}')),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Login'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  // ** assign return value to an observable **
                  return lx.result.value = await Get.dialog(
                      AlertDialog(
                          content: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              RaisedButton(
                                child: Text('Good Login'),
                                onPressed: () => Get.back(result: true),
                                // ** result: returns this value up the call stack **
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 5,),
                              RaisedButton(
                                child: Text('Bad Login'),
                                onPressed: () => Get.back(result: false),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                      )
                  );},
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but the dialog opens again.